Computing the operator norm of a rank one matrix
Suppose I have $x$ is i.i.d. from some distribution, and we know that $||x|| \leq l$, and $\lambda_{max}(x x^\top) \leq c$.
I am interested in computing $||x x^\top||_{op}$. My attempt is the following:
$$ ||x x^\top||_{op} = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}((x x^\top)^\top x x^\top)} = \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(x  x^\top x x^\top)}$$
By our assumptions on the norm of $x$ and max eigenvalue, I am concluding that:
\begin{equation} ||x x^\top||_{op} \leq \sqrt{ l^2 c} \quad (1) \end{equation}
However, my understanding is that one can also bound the operator norm by either:
$$ ||x x^\top||_{op} \leq ||x||_1 \cdot ||x||_\infty$$
$$ ||x x^\top||_{op} \leq ||x||_2 \cdot ||x||_2$$
This would yield an upper bound of
$$ ||x x^\top||_{op} \leq l^2  \quad (2)$$
My impression was the first bound (1) should align with the second (2), but this is not the case. Is there anything wrong with my bound in the first computation?

$|xx|=\lambda_\max(xx^T)=|x|^2$. Therefore $|xx^T|\le\min(l^2,c)$. This upper bound is sharper than those in (1) and (2).

If $\|x\| \leq l$, then you automatically have $\lambda_{max}(xx^T) = \|x\|^2 \leq l^2$, so you can choose $c = l^2$ and the two results do align.

In fact, since $xx^T$ is positive semidefinite, you also have $\|xx^T\|_{op} = \lambda_{max}(xx^T)$.
